# If $a_n$,$b_n \in \mathbb{S}^2$ and $\delta_n \to 0$ s.t. $\Big|\dfrac{a_n-b_n}{\delta_n}\Big| \leq 1$, does the quotient converge to tangent plane?

Tags: geometry

Suppose that $a_n$ and $b_n$ are two sequences in $\mathbb{S}^2$. It is assumed that $a_n$ and $b_n$ converge to $y \in \mathbb{S}^2$ and there is a sequence of real number $\delta_n \to 0$ such that $\left|\dfrac{a_n-b_n}{\delta_n}\right| \leq 1$. Is it possible to conclude that there is subsequence of $\dfrac{a_n-b_n}{\delta_n}$ converging to a vector in tangent plane of $\mathbb{S}^2$ at $y$?

Comment: As you've stated it, the answer is "no". Any convergent subsequence will converge to a vector *at the origin* which should be normal to $y$, and therefore *when transated* to $y$ will be in the tangent plane.

Comment: How to prove that the limit is normal to $y$?